# If the Puppeteer worlds are traveling near light-speed, shouldn't their time be dilated?

Tags: larry-niven, ringworld, known-space

If it were, the time that Louis Wu spent there would have seemed very short, but would have actually been years. Was this ever addressed?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well, it really depends on how long he was there, and the exact speed of the Fleet. Time dilation increases way faster as you approach the speed of light.

[image: Time dilation formula]

[image: Time dilation factor]

At 0.9c the dilation factor is [about 2.29](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1/sqrt%281-0.9%5E2%29); at 0.95c [about 3.20](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1/sqrt%281-0.95%5E2%29); at 0.97c [about 4.11](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1/sqrt%281-0.7%5E2%29); at 0.99c [about 7.09](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1/sqrt%281-0.99%5E2%29); at 0.999c is [about 22.37](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1/sqrt%281-0.999%5E2%29); and at 0.9999c it's [about 70.71](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1/sqrt%281-0.9999%5E2%29).

Even if the Fleet was travelling at 0.9999c, staying there for one day would only mean 70 days to the outside world, which is a difference small enough to be ignored. At slower speeds the differences get meaningless pretty fast. They just took a short walk across a few stepping discs and spent some time discussing with Chiron. I think one day is a very generous upper bound on that.

Of course, if they were going just slightly [faster than that](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1/sqrt%281-0.9999999%5E2%29), the differences would be more much pronounceable.

Comment: One thing to remember about time dilation is that the acceleration slows down the closer you approximate c. It's perfectly reasonable that they might just stop accelerating after a while, it would cause more headaches and not really be speeding them up any.

Comment: Also, see my answer (http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3019/how-close-was-the-puppeteers-homeworld-to-the-ringworld/3047#3047) to see what the speed likely was, around 0.7-0.8c, not quite enough to have a serious affect, but close enough to say that one is approaching light speed.

Answer (score 3):

Remember, from the Fleet's point of view, the rest of the galaxy is what's moving and experiencing time dilation. The impossibility of reconciling these two points of view when someone visits the Fleet in a hyperdrive ship is basically the reason why ftl travel isn't actually possible. So if you're on Earth, the puppeteers appear to experience about 0.6 days for every day that you experience (the Fleet is travelling at 0.8c), but if you're with the Fleet, then Earth experiences 0.6 days for every day that you experience.

Comment: No, that is not how time dilation works. Time dilation is very real, http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/relativ/airtim.html

Comment: Yes, time dilation is absolutely real. But it depends on your inertial frame of reference -- there's a reason why relativity is called relativity. It really is true that the answer to "What's the difference in time dilation between the Earth and the Fleet of Worlds" depends on whether you're currently on the Earth or on the Fleet of Worlds.

Comment: the thing is, if the fleet has been accelerated with respect to earth, that is discernible from the case of the earth being accelerated with respect to the fleet; it was the fleet that was accelerated, so it is on the fleet worlds where time would dilate, and not vice versa.

Comment: No, it doesn't work that way either. The answer really does depend on your inertial frame.

Comment: The two viewpoints get reconciled because of relativistic effects during the course of the observer's exit from the Fleet of Worlds, acceleration back towards Earth, and deceleration from 0.x c to Earth's local reference frame.

Comment: The viewpoints *would* get reconciled if you travelled from the Fleet of Worlds to Earth in normal space, but if you use hyperdrive then all bets are off, you can't say what will happen (unless you're the author).